# ClassCastException testing Spring Cloud Stream producer only when another test is also executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-cloud-stream

New to Spring Cloud Stream, using the latest 3.1.3, I am attempting to successfully write one of each type (Supplier, Function, Consumer) and matching tests, just so that I get a good grasp of the technology before I start implementing real application code.

Here is the git repo for the example : https://github.com/gjobin/spring-cloud-stream-test

That being said, the test for my producer yields a weird loader exception, but only when my `functionTest()` is also included in the suite. If I execute the producer test alone, it passes as expected.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.model.Person cannot be cast to class [B (com.example.model.Person is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at com.example.stream.PersonStreamTest.deserializePayload(PersonStreamTest.java:89)
    at com.example.stream.PersonStreamTest.receiveMessage(PersonStreamTest.java:84)
    at com.example.stream.PersonStreamTest.producerTest(PersonStreamTest.java:48)
```

Here is my test code :

```
import ...

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Import({TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class})
@ExtendWith(TestLoggerFactoryExtension.class)
@EmbeddedKafka
class PersonStreamTest {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;


    @Test
    void producerTest() {
        Message<Person> message = receiveMessage(Person.class, "thasource.destination");
        assertThat(message.getPayload()).isEqualTo(Person.builder().firstname("fn").lastname("ln").build());
        String key = (String) message.getHeaders().get("kafka_messageKey");
        assert key != null;
        assertThat(UUID.fromString(key).toString()).isEqualTo(key);
    }

    @Test
    void functionTest() {
        MessageHeaders messageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(Map.of("kafka_messageKey", "theKey"));
        Message<Person> sendMessage = new GenericMessage<>(Person.builder().firstname("firstname").lastname("lastname").build(), messageHeaders);
        output.clear();
        input.send(sendMessage, "thasource.destination");

        Message<Person> message = receiveMessage(Person.class, "uppercased.destination");
        assertThat(message.getPayload()).isEqualTo(Person.builder().firstname("firstname").lastname("LASTNAME").build());
        String key = (String) message.getHeaders().get("kafka_messageKey");
        assert key != null;
        assertThat(key).isEqualTo("theKey");
    }

    @Test
    void consumerTest() {
        MessageHeaders messageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(Map.of("kafka_messageKey", "theKey"));
        Person entity = Person.builder().firstname("firstname").lastname("LASTNAME").build();
        Message<Person> sendMessage = new GenericMessage<>(entity, messageHeaders);
        output.clear();

        TestLogger logger = TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger(PersonStream.class);
        input.send(sendMessage, "uppercased.destination");
        assertThatIterable(logger.getLoggingEvents()).isEqualTo(List.of(info(entity.toString())));
    }

    private <T> Message<T> receiveMessage(Class<T> clazz, String bindingName) {
        Message<byte[]> receivedMessage = output.receive(1000, bindingName);
        assertThat(receivedMessage).isNotNull();
        return new GenericMessage<>(deserializePayload(clazz, receivedMessage), receivedMessage.getHeaders());
    }

    private <T> T deserializePayload(Class<T> clazz, Message<byte[]> m) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(m.getPayload(), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My application.yml configuration

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default

  cloud:
    function:
      definition: source;uppercase;sink

    stream:
      bindings:
        source-out-0:
          destination: thasource
        uppercase-in-0:
          destination: thasource
          group: ingestor
        uppercase-out-0:
          destination: uppercased
        sink-in-0:
          destination: uppercased
          group: ingestor
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          producer-properties:
            compression.type: zstd
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            max.request.size: 15728640
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        bindings:
          uppercase-out-0:
            producer:
              messageKeyExpression: headers['kafka_receivedMessageKey']
```

My stream fuctions are defined as

```
import ...

@Service
@Slf4j
public class PersonStream {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<Person>> source() {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(Person.builder()
                        .firstname("fn")
                        .lastname("ln")
                        .build())
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Person, Person> uppercase() {
        return p -> {
            p.setLastname(p.getLastname().toUpperCase());
            return p;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Person> sink() {
        return p -> log.info(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: There could be a lot going on there, but the main issue I see is you are attempting to use Embedded Kafka and Test Binder. Not sure what do you expect from it, given that test binder binds to its internal channels exposed via Input/OutputDestinations and has no knowledge of Kafka

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I see what you mean, however the app would not start and fail if I don't provide it with a local or embedded Kafka. Am I missing something in the way to start and use the Test Binder correctly ?

Comment: The best thing you can do is create a sample and commit it to Github and provide a link so we can take a look

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Here is the repo : https://github.com/gjobin/spring-cloud-stream-test. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your application contains a lot of dependencies that are not needed and rather complex configuration for a case where you are trying to learn something. It also makes it difficult for us to review. So, here are few pointers; If you are using embedded kafka you don't need docker image if it, you don't need test binder for it either - just look at some embedded kafka tests that we have in as we are using it ourselves. Since you have 3 functions the only configuration you need is `spring.cloud.function.definition=source;uppercase;sink`. So, slim it down and introduce complexity incrementally

Comment: Also, if you do want to use test binder then look at some of these tests- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/main/core/spring-cloud-stream-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Thank you for the great information and examples.
I understand how to use the test binder and refactored my code to simplify the use case. However still running into issues with embedded kafka for IT tests (PersonStreamIT class). My consumer does not get any message and it seems the topic does not even get created on the broker, but the app still runs, although with completely different headers on the message. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Please look at our Kafka tests to see how we are using embedded kafka. For example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/b5f9c5093b010f7c8a73856d54580d80854f8568/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/bootstrap/KafkaBinderBootstrapTest.java#L36

Comment: Somehow trying to replicate what's in that class, the `embeddedKafka` is null.
I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Would you mind taking a look at my last GH commit, the class PersonStreamIT, and specifically the `e2e` test, along with the comment at the bottom of the class. Thanks again and sorry to be persistent 